# Class "veins::ViensInetManger"not found

Tags: omnet++

I have an issue When I run the omnetpp.ini this error message appear

A runtime error occurred:

> Class "Veins::VeinsInetManager" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel() -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) Scenario (id=1), during network setup
> Launch a debugger with the following command?"

Note : the include file is exist!

How I Can resolve it please  ??

I tried to remove the viens manger in the code , but the error is still occured !

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77447476/edit) tthe question and add [mcve]?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.